# C++ bi-directional association: object access with smart pointers seems to corrupt the instance

Tags: qt, c++11, shared-ptr, bidirectional, weak-ptr

I had a bi-directional object association implemented with raw pointers and it worked without flaw. Then I decided to **refactor my code with smart pointers** and all of a sudden **a string member** (*depName*) of one of the classes (*Department*) is **no longer accesssible after object initialization**. I checked if the parameter gets passed correctly and in the constructor everything is ok. The member gets the intended value. But afterwards it is no longer accessible and **in addition** to that **the code that ran smoothly before, now crashes**. I have no clue why.

EDIT: The same seems to be happening to the string variable name used for in the Manager class. END EDIT

- The code compiles without errors or even warnings.
- I'm working with qt creator 3.3.0 and mingw compiler 5.4.0
- The System claims there is a "Segmentation fault".

This is my code (sorry it's a lot - I reduced it as much as I dared):

in the **header files**:

```
    class Manager;
    class Department
    {
    private:
        string depName;
        shared_ptr<Manager> head;
        vector <shared_ptr<Manager>> depMembers;
    public:
        Department(string depName, shared_ptr<Manager> head);
        virtual ~Department();
        string getDepName() const;
        void setDepName(const string &value);
        void addMember(shared_ptr<Manager> newMember);
        void removeMember(shared_ptr<Manager> who);
        const shared_ptr<Manager>getHead() const;
        void setHead(shared_ptr<Manager>value);
        double sumOfIncome();
        void show();
    };
    //--------------------------------
    class Department;
    class  Manager
    {
        private:
            string name;
            float salary;
            float bonus;//Bonus ist ein Prozentsatz
            weak_ptr<Department> myDepartment;
    //        Department * myDepartment; //With this raw pointer the code still worked*
        public:
            Manager(string, float, float);
            virtual ~Manager();
            float income()const ;
            string toString()const ;
            double calcBonus() const;
            shared_ptr<Department> getMyDepartment() const;
            void setMyDepartment(shared_ptr<Department> abt);
            float getSalary() const;
            string getName() const;
    };
```

in the **cpp files**:
department.cpp

```
    //---------------------------------------------------
    Department::Department(string depName, shared_ptr<Manager>head)
        :depName(depName),head(nullptr)
    {
        this->setHead(head);
        cout << "\nIn constructor parameter depName: " + depName;
        cout << "\n instancevariable " + this->depName << endl;
    }
    //--------------------------------
    Department::~Department()
    {}
    //--------------------------------
    string Department::getDepName() const
    {
        return this->depName;
    }
    //--------------------------------
    void Department::setDepName(const string &value)
    {
        depName = value;
    }
    //--------------------------------
    void Department::addMember(shared_ptr<Manager> newMember)
    {
        depMembers.push_back(newMember);
    }
    //--------------------------------
    void Department::removeMember(shared_ptr<Manager> who)
    {
        vector<shared_ptr<Manager>>::iterator itMember = depMembers.begin();
        //Iterator must be dereferenced to access data
        while( *itMember != who){
            itMember++;
        }
        if( *itMember == who)
            depMembers.erase( itMember);
    }
    //--------------------------------
    const shared_ptr<Manager> Department::getHead() const
    {
        return head;
    }
    //--------------------------------
    void Department::setHead(shared_ptr<Manager>value)
    {
        if( head != nullptr && head->getMyDepartment()!= nullptr)
            head->setMyDepartment(nullptr);//department of old head is deleted

        //new head of department assigned
        head = value;
        //bidirektionaler access
        if(head !=nullptr)
            head->setMyDepartment( shared_ptr<Department>(this));
    }
    //--------------------------------
    double Department::sumOfIncome()
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < depMembers.size(); i++){
            sum += depMembers[i]->getSalary() ;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    //--------------------------------
    void Department::show()
    {
        cout <<"----------------" << endl;
        cout << "Department: " << this->depName << " run by " << head->getName()<<endl;
        cout <<"----------------" << endl;
        cout << "Members: " << endl;
        cout <<"----------------" << endl;
        cout << head->toString() << endl;
        for( unsigned int i=0; i < depMembers.size() ; i++){
            cout <<"----------------" << endl;
            cout << depMembers[i]->toString()<< endl;
        }
        cout <<"----------------" << endl;
    }
```

manager.cpp

```
    //---------------------
    float Manager::getSalary() const
    {
        return salary;
    }
    //----------------------------------
    string Manager::getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
    //----------------------------------
    Manager::Manager(string n, float s, float bon)
        :name(n),salary(s), bonus(bon)
    {}
    //----------------------------------
    Manager::~Manager(){}
    //----------------------------------
    float Manager::income()const
    {
        return (salary + calcBonus() );
    }
    //----------------------------------
    string Manager::toString() const
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << name << "\n heads the department ";
        shared_ptr<Department> dep = myDepartment.lock();
        if( dep !=nullptr)
            ss<< dep->getDepName();
        else ss << " NONE ";
        ss << "\nBonus: " << calcBonus();
        ss << "\nIncome: " << income();
        return ss.str();
    }
    //----------------------------------
    double Manager::calcBonus()const
    {
        shared_ptr<Department> dep = myDepartment.lock();
        if(dep != nullptr)
            return dep->sumOfIncome()* bonus;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    //----------------------------------
    shared_ptr<Department> Manager::getMyDepartment() const
    {
    //    if( !meineAbteilung->expired())
        return myDepartment.lock();
    }
    //----------------------------------
    void Manager::setMyDepartment( shared_ptr<Department> dep)
    {
        myDepartment = dep;
    }
    //----------------------------------
```

test run:

```
    int main(){
        shared_ptr<Department> itDepartment 
            = make_shared<Department>("IT",make_shared<Manager>("Julia", 66066, 0.15));

        itDepartment->show();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include a backtrace of the crash you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure how to supply that. Do your mean a stack trace? I know how to do that in eclipse (Java), but not in QT.

But I can supply this information:


The programm crashes trying to access the name of the manager in the show method, which is also not available any more.
The System claims that there is a segmentation error.

Comment: You could run it on gdb, but, if you want to do it graphically, just run the project in debug mode (`F5` on Qt Creator) and it will stop when it crashes. Then, it will show you the callstack. More info here: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could tag *John Zwinck*'s answer as correct - (thank you John!), but I myself needed more information to understand the issue, so I have decided to post my own answer.

There are 2 problems with my approach:

1. **`shared_ptr` should never be made from raw pointer-variables**, because each initialization of a `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer will create a new manager-object with its own reference count. An existing manager-object will only get used if a new `shared_ptr` is created from one of the `shared_ptr`s or `weak_ptr`s of the existing manager-object. (Somehow the book I read managed to omit this important bit of information.) **`this` is a raw pointer**, so in my constructor of Department a second manager-object is created. The reference count of the second manager-object decreases to 0 as soon as the constructor is left - deleting the object I just finished creating. A `shared_ptr` should therefore never be created from `this` itself. It's a fatal flaw.
2. Since in bidirectional associations the object needs to pass on a pointer to itself, the **C++-library contains a class `enable_shared_from_this`**, which supplies some template magic to make a `shared_ptr` from this in the background. Unfortunately **`shared_from_this()` is not available in the constructor**, because the object-build is not finished. The conclusion is, that an object cannot pass a reference to itself another object in the constructor. There is just no way to get that to work. **A workaround, calling `setHead()` directly after the constructor is the way out.** Coming from Java, where passing `this` from the constructor is the norm, this is something you just have to live with...

Apart from John Zwinck nudging me in the right direction, I found a paper from **David Kieras** very helpful:
http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/C++11_smart_ptrs.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It's crashing because nobody owns some of the objects.  This is a big red flag:

```
head->setMyDepartment(shared_ptr<Department>(this));
```

There is such a thing as `enable_shared_from_this` but you aren't using it, so constructing a `shared_ptr` from `this` is nonsense, specifically because you allow it to go out of scope right away.  That will call `delete this` which you don't want.

Somebody needs to own these objects from outside.  They can't just own each other (circular reference).

Comment: 1. I don't see why there is not a clear owner or why the object gets erased:
If I try to follow the reference counters for shared pointers I always still have the `shared_ptr<Department> itDepartment` which I declared in main. So how can the passing of `this` as an argument to the Manager-object erase the object in whose constructor I am currently? 
Therefore the instance variable "head" - which is part of the department object - should also not be erased.

Comment: 2. I tried implementing the whole thing with shared_ptr on both sides. It still didn't work. 
Also I understood, that you need weak_ptr, so that the objects get erased completely at the end of the program. 
Without a weak pointer on one side, the circular reference would then prevent deletion.

Comment: 3. I tried your recommendation anyway, but it didn't work. I had a compiler error somewhere in the C++-Library, 
because supposedly I was trying to access a protected part of some class? 

So sorry - I was very hopeful, when I read your answer, but it didn't resolve my problem - or my understanding of it.

Comment: @schulefant: Basically you cannot construct a `shared_ptr` from `this`.  It doesn't share a reference count with any other shared pointers, so it deletes `this` too early.

Comment: I have to admit I don't understand the reasoning behind this. Main has a shared pointer to the same object, so shared_ptr from this should be the second shared pointer. It doesn't make sense that it deletes. But I'll just accept that this is so. So no shared_ptr or weak_ptr from this. 
So how do I **implement bidirectional associations with smart pointers correctly**? And second - what on earth are weak_ptr for - if not to ensure correct object deletion in the case of circular (bidirectional) references? I thought that that was their main purpose.

Comment: You can only construct a second `shared_ptr` by copying an existing one.  If you create two independent `shared_ptr`s pointing to the same raw pointer and the two don't know about each other, how is either of them going to realize they should not `delete` until the other one is dead?  If you have two kids and you tell each one of them you need milk from the store, you will end up with two jugs of milk.  The correct use of `weak_ptr` likewise is to construct them from a `shared_ptr`, not from a raw pointer.  You're right about their purpose.